# How to check the resolution of the image

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

How to check the resolution of the image which is stored on Google Drive using Google Apps Script.

```
 var childFile = files.next();
  data = [ 
    childFile.getName(),
    childFile.getDateCreated(),
    childFile.getUrl(),
    childFile.getLastUpdated(),
    childFile.getDescription(),
    childFile.getSize()
  ];
```

In the above code I am able to get the size of the image but how can I get the resolution of image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the Google Drive API to get the image size and other [EXIF data](https://ctrlq.org/code/20059-image-exif-and-location). Make sure you have enabled Drive API under the Developer Console for the Apps Script project.

```
function getImageSize(fileID) {

  var api = "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/" + fileID;

  var meta = JSON.parse(UrlFetchApp.fetch(api, {
    headers: {
      "Authorization": "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()
    }
  }).getContentText());

  Logger.log(meta.imageMediaMetadata.height);
  Logger.log(meta.imageMediaMetadata.width);
}
```